# How to use hamcrest matchers in Testng assertEquals?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, testng, hamcrest

I am currently using testng `assertEquals` and softassertion, No I have a scenario of validation wher the actual is a complete `String` and the expected is a substring.

#### Code

```
assertThat("This is actual string", containsString("expected"));
```

#### Error message

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.hamcrest.Matcher.describeMismatch(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/hamcrest/Description;)V

#### Code

```
softAssert.assertEquals("This is actual string", containsString("actual"));
```

#### Error message

> java.lang.AssertionError:
>   The following asserts failed: expected [a string containing "actual"] but found [This is actual string] Expected :a string containing "actual" Actual   :This is actual string

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with assertEquals, You can do it using assertTrue. Use below code,

```
String actual="This is actual string";
assertTrue(actual.contains("actual"));
```

Comment: Thanks for input, I tried the same,If the assertion fails, the assertion error says expected true, actual as fasle. The general assertion error message will be like Expected:actual Actual:This is actual string

Comment: @BharathanKumaran Couldn't understand the comment. Does your problem solved?

Comment: I am already using the above one, the downside of the above one is if the contains fails, the assertion error log will say expected true, actual false,

Where the the hamcrest assertion
will say expected "expected string" actual This is actual string,